# Logging in to a website a curl-based POST request not working

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I'm trying to download a page, reddit.com/gold, one has to be logged in to access it, so my first instinct was to use curl in order to post the login form data and log in.

I came this far: http://pastie.org/3387061

The script outputs the page that is presented to you if you're not logged in, so I'm fairly certain it isn't working as it should.

Here's the login form, if that's needed (I de-minified it): http://pastie.org/3387065

Thanks for reading and for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the same value for CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR on both requests and also add an option CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

try using chrome inspector to login and see what actual POST vars are being sent, there might be something you've missed